# if statement causes while loop to run forever in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a project to convert csv files into html. My problem is that my code will run forever and I have to stop it manually. However, when I remove the if statement, all of the print methods are executed how I intended. Here's the code below.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TableMaker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter file path.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filepath = scanner.nextLine();
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                if (scanner.next().charAt(0) == '#') {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print("<tr>");
                for (int n = 0; n < row.length; n++) {
                    System.out.print("<td>" + row[n] + "</td>");
                }
                System.out.print("</tr>" + "\r\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If this helps at all, whenever I stop it manually it says it has exit code 130.

Comment: The code is waiting for input *on the standard input stream*. That’s probably not what you want, since you’re otherwise trying to read from a file.

Comment: `scanner.next().charAt(0)` what is `scanner`? From where it tries to read?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to achieve in the if statement is skip lines in the file provided to the `System.in` that starts with `#`.

So you need to check if the first character of `line` is `#`, and not of `scanner.next().charAt(0)` which hangs while it waits for another input to stdin.

try:

```java
if (line.charAt(0) == '#') {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!